# How to prevent a previously defined object updating when a new object is filtered (new object created based on original object)

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, angular6

I want to filter an array of object based on their year, but whenever I filter out a set of values, it filters the values in the newly created object and also the original object. But I want the original object to stay the same so I can apply different filters.

I've tried using .assign, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object)) and the clone deep function.

component code

```
export class LeaderboardComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "Leaderboard"
  public navList = [];
  public navFilterList = [];
  routeCount = 0; 
  logsCount = 0;
  completeJourneys = 0;
  selectFilter = "";
  selectDateFilter = "";
  currentDate = new Date;
  minutes = 1000 * 60;
  hours = this.minutes * 60;
  days = this.hours * 24;
  month = this.days * 30;
  years = this.days * 365;
  currTimestamp = this.currentDate.getTime();
  clonedObject;
  objCopy = [];

  constructor(private leaderboardService: LeaderboardService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.leaderboardService.getNavList()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.navList = data;
       this.objCopy = Object.assign([], data);
      console.log("here");
      console.log(this.objCopy);
    });
  }


  orderByDate(){
    console.log(this.objCopy);
    var tempLogArray = 0;
    this.navFilterList = this.objCopy;

    if(this.selectDateFilter != "all"){

      for(var i = 0; i < this.navFilterList.length; i ++){
        for(var j = 0; j < this.navFilterList[i].user.routes.length; j ++){
          for(var k = 0; k < this.navFilterList[i].user.routes[j].logs.length; k++){
                var logDate = new Date(this.navFilterList[i].user.routes[j].logs[k].attemptDate);
                this.navFilterList[i].user.routes[j].logs[k].timestamp = logDate.getTime(); 
          }
          this.navFilterList[i].user.routes[j].logs =  this.navFilterList[i].user.routes[j].logs.filter(log => ((this.currTimestamp - log.timestamp)/this.years)  < 1);
        }
      }
      console.log("here year");
    }
}
}
```

html code which calls the filter by date function

```
              <select [(ngModel)]="selectDateFilter"  (change)="orderByDate()" class="form-group" style="width: 100px;" >
                <option  disabled selected value="" >Order by: </option>
                <option  value = "week">Last 7 Days</option>
                  <option  value = "month">Last Month</option>
                  <option  value = "year" >Last Year</option>
                  <option  value = "all" >All Time</option>
                </select>
```

I expect the objCopy to always contain the data which is taken from the JSON file in an API but instead its updated with the filtered data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables that are assigned a non-primitive value are given a reference to that value. That reference points to the object’s location in memory. The variables don’t actually contain the value.

So try using the `spread` operator

`this.navFilterList = [...this.objCopy];`

EDIT:

I noticed you are modifying the object, which then means the `spread` operator and `slice` will not work because they are shallow copy not deep clone.

Your original method `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object))` will work for deep clone:

`this.navFilterList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.objCopy));`

Comment: `this.objCopy.slice()` will achieve the same shallow copy

Comment: @bryan60, yep, whichever OP prefers, I personally like the spread operator.

Comment: The same issue is still happening on both of those solutions. But I think the issue os that as @penleychan mentioned its pointing to memory, so even if I'm using the spread operator or the slice, it's too late because whats in memory has already been updated?